# Parsing Regular expression from YAML file adds extra \

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of regular expression I am using to scrape lot of specific fields from a text document. Those all work fine when used directly inside the python script.

But I thought of putting them in a YAML file and reading from there. Here's how it looks:

```
# Document file for Regular expression patterns for a company invoice

---

    issuer: ABCCorp
    fields:
      invoice_number: INVOICE\s*(\S+)
      invoice_date: INVOICE DATE\s*(\S+)
      cusotmer_id: CUSTOMER ID\s*(\S+)
      origin: ORIGIN\s*(.*)ETD
      destination: DESTINATION\s*(.*)ETA
      sub_total: SUBTOTAL\s*(\S+)
      add_gst: SUBTOTAL\s*(\S+)
      total_cost: TOTAL USD\s*(\S+)
      description_breakdown: (?s)(DESCRIPTION\s*GST IN USD\s*.+?TOTAL CHARGES)
      package_details_fields: (?s)(WEIGHT\s*VOLUME\s*.+?FLIGHT|ROAD REFERENCE)
      mawb_hawb: (?s)((FLIGHT|ROAD REFERENCE).*(MAWB|MASTER BILL)\s*.+?GOODS COLLECTED FROM)
```

When I retrieve it using pyyml in python, it is adding a string quote around that (which is ok as I can add r'' later) but I see it is also adding extra \ in between the regex. That would make the regex go wrong when used in code now

```
import yaml
with open(os.path.join(TEMPLATES_DIR,"regex_template.yml")) as f:
    my_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)

print(my_dict)

{'issuer': 'ABCCorp', 'fields': {'invoice_number': 'INVOICE\\s*(\\S+)', 'invoice_date': 'INVOICE DATE\\s*(\\S+)', 'cusotmer_id': 'CUSTOMER ID\\s*(\\S+)', 'origin': 'ORIGIN\\s*(.*)ETD', 'destination': 'DESTINATION\\s*(.*)ETA', 'sub_total': 'SUBTOTAL\\s*(\\S+)', 'add_gst': 'SUBTOTAL\\s*(\\S+)', 'total_cost': 'TOTAL USD\\s*(\\S+)', 'description_breakdown': '(?s)(DESCRIPTION\\s*GST IN USD\\s*.+?TOTAL CHARGES)', 'package_details_fields': '(?s)(WEIGHT\\s*VOLUME\\s*.+?FLIGHT|ROAD REFERENCE)', 'mawb_hawb'
```

How to read the right regex as I have it in yaml file? Does any string written in yaml file gets a quotation mark around that when read in python because that is a string?

EDIT:

The main regex in yaml file is:

```
INVOICE\s*(\S+)
```

Output in dict is:

```
'INVOICE\\s*(\\S+)'
```

Comment: What do you mean it is "adding extra \ in between the regex"?

Comment: I will add edit.

Comment: added.. if u check the input in yaml file.. regex. and the dict output.. dict has extra \ in between regex

Comment: I didn't downvote it. By the way, it was the 'between' that through me off. Go into `python` with no arguments. At `>>>` prompt enter: `d = {'x': r'ab\sc'}; print(d)` . You will see: `{'x': 'ab\\sc'}`. I don't think you have an extra backslash. The double backslash is how you enter a single backslash in a string."

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding it. I did this also: 

d = {'x': 'ab\sc'}; print(d) And it still shows 2 \. 

Why is it adding that? This wud make issue for me when I read the regex from the dict now as it wud read 2 \\ in the regex when original regex does't have that

Comment: That's my point. Enter: len('\\'). It will come back as 1.

Comment: so heres the point- when u just print a dict it adds 2 \. But when u retrieve it from the dict using key it shows the correct one. So is it more of a print thing which adds another \ to a string on to console?

Comment: See my long comment/answer/

Comment: The bottom line is that when you print a Python object other than a string, it prints a representation of the object showing how you would have created it. And if the object contains a string and that string contains a backslash, you would have doubled up on that backslash when entering it.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to do as a comment.

The backslash character is used to escape special characters. For example:

```
'\n': newline
'\a': alarm
```

When you use it before a letter that has no special meaning it is just taken to be a backslash character:

```
'\s': backslash followed by 's'
```

But to be sure, whenever you want to enter a backslash character in a string and not have it interpreted as the start of an escape sequence, you double it up:

```
'\\s': also a backslash followed by a 's'
'\\a': a backslash followed by a 'a'
```

If you use a r'' type literal, then a backslash is never interpreted as the start of an escape sequence:

```
r'\a': a backslash followed by 'a' (not an alarm character)
r'\n': a backslash followed by n (not a newline -- however when used in a regex. it will match a newline)
```

Now here is the punchline:

When you print out these Python objects, such as:

```
d = {'x': 'ab\sd'}
print(d)
```

Python will print the string representation of the dictionary and the string will print:
`'ab\\sd'`. If you just did:

```
print('ab\sd')
```

You would see `ab\sd`. Quite a difference.

Why the difference. See if this makes sense:

```
d = {'x': 'ab\ncd'}
print(d)
print('ab\ncd')
```

Results:

```
d = {'x': 'ab\ncd'}
ab
cd
```

The bottom line is that when you print a Python object other than a string, it prints a representation of the object showing how you would have created it. And if the object contains a string and that string contains a backslash, you would have doubled up on that backslash when entering it.

**Update**

To process your `my_dict`: Since you did not provide the complete value of `my_dict`, I can only use a truncated version for demo purposes. But this will demonstrate that `my_dict` has perfectly good regular expressions:

```
import re

my_dict = {'issuer': 'ABCCorp', 'fields': {'invoice_number': 'INVOICE\\s*(\\S+)', 'invoice_date': 'INVOICE DATE\\s*(\\S+)'}}

fields = my_dict['fields']
invoice_number_re = fields['invoice_number']
m = re.search(invoice_number_re, 'blah-blah INVOICE 12345 blah-blah')
print(m[1])
```

Prints:

```
12345
```

If you are going to be using the same regular expressions over and over again, then it is best to compile them:

```
import re

my_dict = {'issuer': 'ABCCorp', 'fields': {'invoice_number': 'INVOICE\\s*(\\S+)', 'invoice_date': 'INVOICE DATE\\s*(\\S+)'}}

#compile the strings to regular expressions
fields = my_dict['fields']
for k, v in fields.items():
    fields[k] = re.compile(v)

invoice_number_re = fields['invoice_number']
m = invoice_number_re.search('blah-blah INVOICE 12345 blah-blah')
print(m[1])
```

Comment: I am lost right now. How do I fetch it correctly. It is fetching from a dict with an added "\". That is spoiling the whole regex pattern for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653873/reading-a-string-from-a-dict-adds-an-extra

Comment: Thanks. I did similar. Figured out later that its just whiile printing its an issue. While reading from a dict, I don't need to add raw string